# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given al implementar filtros de busqueda en un query

Tags: php, mariadb

Tengo errores en las líneas 119 y 137, los cuales son : mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given y Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool, llevo ya un buen rato intentando solucionarlo pero no lo consigo. La query general se hace sin problemas pero cuando intento buscar un tipo de servicio en especifico el programa marca esos errores.

```
<?php
                        //Filtro de busqueda.
                        if ($_POST['buscar'] == '') {
                            $_POST['buscar'] = ' ';
                        }
                        if ($_POST["buscar"] == '' and $_POST['tipo_servicio'] == '' and $_POST['buscafechadesde'] == '' and $_POST['buscafechahasta'] == '') {
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM cotizaciones";
                        } else {
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM cotizaciones";
                            if ($_POST["tipo_servicio"] != '') {
                                $query .= " AND tipo_servicio = '" . $_POST['tipo_servicio'] . "' ";
                            }

                            if ($_POST["buscafechadesde"] != '') {
                                $query .= " AND fecha BETWEEN '" . $_POST["buscafechadesde"] . "' AND '" . $_POST["buscafechahasta"] . "' ";
                            }
                        }


                        $sql = $conexion->query($query); //Error aqui

                        $numeroSql = mysqli_num_rows($sql);//Error aqui

                        ?>
                        <p style="font-weight: bold; color:red;"><i
                                    class="mdi mdi-file-document"></i> <?php echo $numeroSql; ?> Resultados
                            encontrados</p>
                    </form>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                            <tr style="background-color:red; color:#FFFFFF;">
                                <th style=" text-align: center;"> Tipo de servicio</th>
                                <th style=" text-align: center;"> Asegurado</th>
                                <th style=" text-align: center;"> Factura</th>
                                <th style=" text-align: center;"> Fecha</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <?php while ($rowSql = $sql->fetch_assoc()) { ?> //Error aqui
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $rowSql["tipo_servicio"]; ?></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $rowSql["asegurado"]; ?></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $rowSql["factura"]; ?></td>
                                    <td style=" text-align: center;"><?php echo $rowSql["fecha_creacion"]; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Cuando uses el método query() para realizar una consulta, comprueba siempre el resultado, porque si la consulta te da error, devolverá false en vez de un recurso resultset. Entonces, si es false, en vez de seguir para adelante puedes recuperar el error y mostrarlo y/o grabarlo en un log.

Answer (score 0):

Hay un error de sintaxis al armar la consulta, en la línea después del `else`: hace falta la clausula `WHERE`. Adicional le estás mandando un `AND` sin tener una comparación previa. Se está generando una consulta con un formato como este:

```
SELECT * FROM cotizaciones AND tipo_servicio = 'xxx' AND fecha BETWEEN 'yyy' AND 'zzz'
-- Falta un WHERE aqui ---^
```

Por otro lado, no recomiendo modificar directamente una superglobal. PHP permite hacerlo, pero no es lo recomendable, tu código es quien debe procesar la entrada. También deberías es tratar de deshacerte lo más pronto posible de la superglobal asignando a una variable, previamente filtrando el contenido para luego ser usado.

```
$_POST['buscar'] = ' '; # [!] No bien
$buscar = $_POST['buscar']; # Bien
$buscar = funcion_de_filtrado($_POST['buscar']); # Mejor
```

Entonces, con los arreglos debería quedar:

```
$buscar = $_POST['buscar'];
$tipo_servicio = $_POST['tipo_servicio'];
$buscafechadesde = $_POST['buscafechadesde'];
$buscafechahasta = $_POST['buscafechahasta'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM cotizaciones";

$subquery = array();
if($tipo_servicio) {
    $subquery[] = "tipo_servicio='$tipo_servicio'";
}
if($buscafechadesde and $buscafechahasta) {
    $subquery[] = "fecha BETWEEN '$buscafechadesde' AND '$buscafechahasta'";
}

if($subquery) { 
    $query .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $subquery); 
}
```

Como puedes observar, la variable `$buscar` no se usa en ningún lado en `$query`. En el código que proporcionaste tampoco la usas. Supongo ese debe ser el término de la búsqueda. Si siempre va considerado ese campo, entonces ya no sería necesario el último if:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM cotizaciones";

$subquery = array("columna_buscar='$buscar'");
if($tipo_servicio) {
    $subquery[] = "tipo_servicio='$tipo_servicio'";
}
if($buscafechadesde and $buscafechahasta) {
    $subquery[] = "fecha BETWEEN '$buscafechadesde' AND '$buscafechahasta'";
}

$query .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $subquery);
```

Comment: Para hacer búsquedas recomiendo hagas un filtro con una longitud mínima de la palabra a buscar. También puedes usar comodines `... LIKE %$buscar%`. Y finalmente ver las [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) para fortalecer la seguridad contra ataques maliciosos.